# wait for Promise.all To continue executing

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to insert products into array and then continue using that array. I don't have an expirience using Promisses. Bellow is my code.
This is the function that I would like to return an array.

```
const findProduct = async function(request) {
  const products = [];

  await Promise.all(
    request.products.forEach(async product => {
      await db
        .get()
        .collection('products')
        .findOne({ _id: product.productId.toString() }, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw new Error('exception!');
          products.push(result);
        });
    })
  )
    .then(() => {
      return products;
    })
    .catch(e => e);
};
```

Products is always undefined.

Shoud I maybe return Promise.all i save it into an array, then use that array?

This is how I plan to use array

```
const purchase = new Purchase(req.body);

const products = await findProduct(req.body);
purchase.products = [...products];
```

Comment: Promise.all takes *an array of promises*, which is **not** what you get back from 1. forEach (not an array) and 2. findOne (not a promise, presumably, as you've passed a callback). Also as you're using async/await you don't need to use then.

Comment: I just need to wait for an array products to be filled, await alone does not do the job. i do not know how to execute that part first, so that I can user that array later in the code.So just wait **forEach** to finish, and that continue.

Comment: Well if you had promises, you *could* put them in Promise.all, so I'd recommend looking into whether the DB library you're using can give you a promise or how you can make your own.

Comment: is .findOne({...}, (err, result)=>{}) correct since promises tend to return (resolve, reject)=>{} and not the other way around

Comment: findOne function is correct, I do get a product from db and push it into products array. The problem is that this code executes after I return products array, so it is never filled.

Comment: I don't like using promises, but I'm not aware of any other way to accomplish this

Comment: @lastSheep you really should get used to Promises and especially `await`/`async`, as it makes many things much easier as soon as you know how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your `findProduct` function, using `async`/`await` syntax doesn't make a lot of sense if you intend to await the result of `findProduct` using `const products = await findProduct(req.body);`

Instead you want to define your function using only Promises.

Firstly, `db.collection.findOne()` makes use of a callback for asynchronous events, to use this in a Promise chain, you must wrap this in a Promise. Which can be done like so:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db
    .get()
    .collection('products')
    .findOne({ _id: product.productId.toString() }, (err, result) => { err ? reject(err) : resolve(result) })
});
```

Here `(err, result) => { err ? reject(err) : resolve(result) }` is just a concise form of

```js
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve(result);
  }
}
```

Next, you must pass an array to `Promise.all()`. Because you already have the array `request.products`, you can convert (or map) each value to it's corresponding Promise to get it's data. This is done using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). When used this way, `Promise.all()` will resolve to an array of product data objects in the same order of `request.products`.

Mixing this in to your code, yields:

```js
const findProduct = function(request) {
  return Promise.all(
    request.products.map(product => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db
          .get()
          .collection('products')
          .findOne({ _id: product.productId.toString() }, (err, result) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result))
      });
    })
  );
};
```

Note here that I removed `.then(()=>products)` (because Promise.all will return products itself thanks to the promise above) and `.catch(e=>e)` (because you shouldn't be ignoring errors like this).

With these changes, you can now use `findProduct` as you have used it in your question.

---

**Update:**

Seems that the MongoDB API is Promises compliant, which means we can remove the Promise callback wrapper and simplify it down to:

```js
const findProduct = function(request) {
  return Promise.all(
    request.products.map(product => {
      return db
        .get()
        .collection('products')
        .findOne({ _id: product.productId.toString() });
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: [This blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) is a great primer on how to understand Promises

Comment: you could try to omit the creation of the promise in the map function and just return the result from findone() since, I assume its a .then() adaptation it will return a Promise that resolves to the return

Comment: @fubar Unfortunately based on the Mongo documentation I was looking at, the API used is not Promises/A+ compliant.

Comment: Ah. Nvm, seems I was looking at the shell docs. You are indeed correct it does support Promises. Will update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I will look at the post you provided, I have a hard time understanding promises.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all()` expects an array of Promises and map will return an array. Since `db` will also return a Promise we just feed those promises into `Promise.all()`

Edit: forgot to return `Promise.all()` which returns a promise so it can be consumed with the `await findproducts()` or `findproducts().then()`

```
const findProduct = function (request) {

return Promise.all(
    request.products.map(product => {
        return db
            .get()
            .collection('products')
            .findOne({ _id: product.productId.toString() }
            });
    })
)};
```

Since quite a lot of people ask: "How do i get something from a Promise?" --> use the resolve value

---

Here a long explanation why this works: `wait()` will return a Promise that is mapped into an array with `map()` which returns this array. So when map is done we have an array with 3 Promises returned by the 3 `wait()` calls. This array is passed into `Promise.all()` which will wait for all the Promises to resolve and resolves itself to an array with all the resolve values of the Promises from the array. Since `findProduct()` will return this Promise from `Promise.all()` when can access it with `findProduct().then()` or `await findProduct()`

```
const start = { products: ['milk', 'butter', 'eggs'] }

const findProduct = function (request) {
    return Promise.all(
        request.products.map(product => {
            return wait(product)
        })
    )
};

function wait(product) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(product) }, 5000)
    })
}

findProduct(start).then(res => console.log(res))
// logs [ 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs' ]
```

Edit: To answer the comment about `.then()` returning a Promise

```
findProduct(start)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.then(res => console.log(res))
// logs [ 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs' ] and undefined

findProduct(start)
.then(res => {console.log(res); return res})
.then(res => console.log(res))
// logs 2x [ 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs' ]
```

Comment: In **then** block products is **undefined**. Isnt it suppose to wait for first part to execute?

Comment: Are you sure (I don't know it and can't test it right now)  that `findOne` will return a Promise if you pass a callback to it? Normally the convention is to not return a Promise if a callback is passed. Furthermore, it does not make sense to throw an error in a `(err, result) => { … }` callback or return any value from that.

Comment: Hehe, that was also what I believed until yesterday. `.then()` will allways return a promise where the return value of the handler is the resolve value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then There fore if the handler returns a value, `then()` will implicitly resolve the returned promise to that value. See updated answer

Comment: I know that you can return a value from a `then` callback and that this is passed forward in the chain. That was not my point. The `(err, result) => { … }` you pass to `.findOne( …, (err, result) => { … })` has nothing to do with Promises, it is the _old fashioned_ callback API.

Comment: And I checked the source of the MongoDB library [node-mongodb-native/lib/operations/execute_operation.js](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/8fe456bc86ba639145e18643c56f981af5279f4b/lib/operations/execute_operation.js#L73) and it is indeed the case that passing the `(err, result) => { … }` will prevent a Promise from beeing created and returned by `findOne`. So your code will result in `.map` returning an array containing only entries beeing `undefined`